# define error for python script to import arcmap

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy

i want to create a simple python script for create one file geodatabase but show me define error

```
# Import arcpy module


Import arcpy



import sys

import os

from arcpy import env

from arcpy.sa import *

# Local variables:

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace, file_gdb)

file_gdb = workspace + "file_gdb"
```

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to explain what you mean by "define error", please?

Comment: Your `file_gdb` variable needs to be defined before creating the FGDB.

Comment: es run now thanx guys,now if i want to import a feature class in file geodatabase that path is a right ? **feature_class = workspace + file_gdb + "feature_class"**

Answer (score 1):

in the first line you should use import arcpy not Import arcpy . when you want to define workspace you should use arcpy.env.workspace.

```
import arcpy

import sys

import os

from arcpy import env

workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
from arcpy.sa import *

# Local variables:

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True



arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace, "file_gdb")
```

Comment: I agree with the little "i" for `import` but, in this instance, there is no need to use `arcpy.env.workspace`, because the `workspace` variable will work fine in the only place it is used (`arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management`).

Comment: yes run now thanx guys,now if i want to import a feature class in file geodatabase that path is a right ?
feature_class = workspace + file_gdb + "feature_class"